# handling multiple checkboxs and push or filter values based on selection

Tags: arrays, reactjs, checkbox

how to handle checkbox is selected or not and push the object if selected and remove if unselected?

this is the initial arr set to state

```
let arr=[{lable:lable1,value:value1}
{lable:lable2,value:value2}
{lable:lable3,value:value3}
]
```

handle function triggered on selecting checkbox

```
  function handleChange(item) {
        let temp = [...arr];
     if (temp.includes(item.value)) {
       temp = temp.filter((value) => value != item.value);
     } else {
       temp.push(item.value);
     }
     setState(temp);
  }
```

multiple checkbox iterated based on array

```
      {arr.map((item, i) => {
        return (
             
                <label className="check-wrap">
                  <input
                    className="check-field"
                    checked={ ? } // how to handle checkbox is selected or not
                    name={item.lable}
                    onChange={() => handleChange(item)}
                    type="checkbox"
                  />
                  <span className="check-label">{item.value}</span>
                </label>
            </div>
))}
```

issue in [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/vigorous-moon-4inbh?file=/src/App.js)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `prevState` instead of referencing the state value directly.

```js
// ... rest of the onChange function
this.setState(prevState => ({
 arr: prevState.arr.includes(temp)
    ? prevState.arr.filter(value => value !== item.value)
    : [...prevState.arr, temp]
}))
```

You can read up on [`setState` operations](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#setstate) in [reactjs](/questions/tagged/reactjs) here

Hooks works on the same principle:

```js
const [arr, setArr] = useState([])

// ...later
setArr(prevArr => prevArr.includes(temp)
  ? prevArr.fitler(value => value !== item.value)
  : [...prevArr, temp]
)
```

Comment: how to do in useState hooks ?

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/vigorous-moon-4inbh?file=/src/App.js can u please look into this code sandbox and see the issue in my code. Thanks in advance

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/friendly-khorana-wwjou?file=/src/App.js